# Could someone tell me what the problem is with my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've just started learning and have just finished this code
if you get 2 answers wrong, your third answer will be wrong even if it's the right number!
Here's my code:

```
secretnum = 9
maxguess = 2
guesscount = 0
guess = int(input('Guess: '))

while guesscount < maxguess:

    if guess == secretnum:
        guesscount = 5
        print('Well done')

    else:
        print('Try Again')
        guesscount += 1
        guess = int(input('Guess: '))
        if guesscount == maxguess:
            print('You Lost!')
```

What's wrong with it?
[Here's a pic of what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Puccw.png)

Comment: Your indentation looks broken.  Also why is `maxguess = 2` if you want the user to be able to make 3 guesses, and why do you ask them for an extra guess after you've already incremented `guesscount`?

Comment: I don't know how to properly paste codes in this site yet , that's probably the reason why my indentations look that why :"
the maxguess used to be  3 but it did it 4 times, so I changed it to 2 to make it 3 times and it worked
What was the cause of that?
and I don't understand the final comment

Comment: People have given you the answer, but they haven't really told you **why**. The problem you are having is that `if guesscount == maxguess` is right after you have incremented the count, and right after you receive the input. So as soon as you get the input, the count has already reached the max, so the condition is true and you print `You lost` (regardless of what the input was). There are multiple ways to solve it (see the many solutions below). They all involve being careful on when you check `if guesscount == maxguess` and when you increment the `guesscount`.

Comment: Thanks Andres! You've helped a lot ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:

```
secretnum = 9
maxguess = 3
guesscount = 0

while guesscount < maxguess:
    guess = int(input('Guess: '))
    if guess == secretnum:
        print('Well done')
        break
    else:
        print('Try Again')
        guesscount += 1

if guesscount == maxguess:
    print("You lost")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
secretnum = 9
maxguess = 3
guesscount = 0
guess = int(input('Guess: '))

while guesscount < maxguess:
    guesscount += 1
    if guesscount == maxguess:
        print('You Lost!')
        break
    if guess == secretnum:
        print('Well done')
        break

    else:
        print('Try Again')
        guess = int(input('Guess: '))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
secret = 9
guesses = 0
max_guesses = 3
while guesses < max_guesses:
    try:
        guess = int(input('Guess: '))
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter a Number!")
        continue
    if guess == secret:
        print("Well done!")
        break
    guesses += 1
if guesses >= max_guesses:
    print("You lost")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python deals with formatting...**

So you should indent your code, because that is the way python is going to get every block of code

[Check out this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfOq5.png)